# doctrine ManyToMany plus additional entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I got a boards and prefixes.

Some prefixes are only in relation with some boards, other prefixes are possible with all boards.

So I got a manyoMany relation between board and prefix.

How can I add these amount of prefixes additional prefixes (marked with the flag `allowedAtAllboards`)?

Or is this flag not a clean solution and I should expand my cross table with all prefixes like

```
prefix_id | board_id
1|1
1|2
1|3
...
```

EDIT:
I got 3 tables:
board with information about the board like id, name ...

prefix with id, name

board_x_prefix with board_id, prefix_id

I need a relation between boards and prefixes and I created the following relation:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Prefix")
 * @JoinTable(name="board_x_prefix",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="prefix_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="board_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 */
```

Now I get all prefixes mapped to the board, depend on the entry in board_x_prefix like this `$board->getPrefixes()`.

```
prefix_id | board_id
1|1
1|2
1|3
2|3
...
```

The problem is, I want additional prefixes which working with all boards so I created the flag `allowedAtAllboards` on the prefix class but of course the amount of these prefixes are not returned by `$board->getPrefixes()`.

Can I handle that in the model (board or prefix) itself that I get all mapped and all prefixes with the flag by `$board->getPrefixes()` or do I have to write a repository class?

Sorry, I hope its now clear

Comment: Can you update your question? Because I'm trying to understand in order to help you, but I can't understand anything...

Comment: I got two tables: board and prefix.
board got the attributes id, title, creationTime and so on.
prefix got id, name, allowedAtAllBoards.
Then I got a cross table with entities like board_id = 1, prefix_id =1, board_id = 1, prefix_id =45...
this is no problem and I can fetch the board prefixes like $board->getPrefixes().
My problem is i got prefixes which must have a relation to ALL boards and for this case i got the flag allowedAtAllBoards but these are not in the amount of $board->getPrefixes()

Comment: I think you need to clarify your relationships and what you are hoping to achieve — as is, this is not apparent.

Comment: sure i can create a repository class with an DQL but is there any possibility to add to the amount of the manyToMany amount additional rows?

Comment: Please add extra information to the question instead of commenting.

Comment: Sorry I didnt found the edit button... Now I've edited it.